# php Problem reading variable name with dot

Tags: php

Unfortunately, when I put the variable name with a dot, it is not possible to read it in php and it does not show anything.
Please see the code.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $show= $_GET['input_18.1']." " .$_GET['input_18.2'];
    echo($show);
}
?>

<form method="get">
    <input name="input_18.1">
    <input name="input_18.2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use it if you know the dot is a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, dot is used in JavaScript code and cannot be changed. Is it possible to display the information?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out, what you're getting in `$_GET`? For example, using `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20575473

Comment: I checked and it is NULL

Comment: this stackoverflow.com/a/20575473 is my Answer