# php session variable is null

Tags: php, session

i am creating session variables to store data in an array of object. this array is assigned to sessions. I am later sending a get call to different page with an id and want to access the corresponding data from the sessions. however i am getting the data as null. here is my code

page 1:

```
session_start();
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $object[$i]->name = $ret_obj[$i]['name'];
    $object[$i]->birthday_date = $ret_obj[$i]['birthday_date'];
    $_SESSION[$i] = $object[$i];
}
```

var_dump of session prints the session variable correctly.

Now in the for loop i am making a call to page 2:

```
page2.php?pid=$i
```

page 2:

```
session_start();
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
print_r($_SESSION[$pid]);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I am getting value in $_SESSION but not in $_SESSION[$pid]

Comment: oops it was pid everywhere... kind of pasted a prev version.

Comment: What if you `echo $pid`? Do you get the expected results?

Comment: it is giving correct value...

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid idea, but what if you are storing `$_SESSION["a$i"]` and use `pid=a$i`? Maybe something is messing up with numeric indexes.

Comment: but shouldn't the $_Session dump print out everything irrespective of indexing typos

Comment: Theoretically it should be fine the way you have, but it is my only idea.

Comment: You should take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797251/notice-unknown-skipping-numeric-key-1-in-unknown-on-line-0.  To clarify, try adding a character prefix instead of just using numbers.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you.  I will add this as an answer to help future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the following post: [Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 1 in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797251/notice-unknown-skipping-numeric-key-1-in-unknown-on-line-0). To clarify, try adding a character prefix instead of just using numbers.

Comment: Also edit `php.ini` into `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Answer (score 1):

If your code supplied here is all of it, then you are saying:

```
$p13nid = $_GET['pid'];
```

Rather than:

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

Which would make it work for you.