# why can't you use a string number as a index in the session variable?

Tags: php, arrays, session, associative-array

example:

```
$_SESSION['10'] = 'testing';
echo $_SESSION['10'];
```

The above will not print out anything...i found out(after a long time of frustration) that you cannot use a string numeral as a index for the $_SESSION variable.  Anyone know why?

Comment: your code is working at my pc. please check you have not forgot to **start a sesstion** `session_start();`

Comment: [Because](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797251/notice-unknown-skipping-numeric-key-1-in-unknown-on-line-0) the keys in `$_SESSION` must be names that could be treated as variables in their own right.

Comment: @someone you sir are a genius and i owe you lots of hours of frustration...lol ty.  can you post as answer, ill check it off asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797380/3709765):

> The PHP session storage mechanism was originally built around
>   "registering" variables, so the keys in `$_SESSION` must be names that
>   could be treated as variables in their own right.
>   This means that `$_SESSION[10]` is invalid, because `$10` wouldn't be
>   a valid variable name, and since `$foo[10]` and `$foo['10']` refer to
>   the same thing, `$_SESSION['10']` is invalid as well.