# Need help passing session using header redirect

Tags: php, arrays, session, oauth, associative-array

I am trying to create a 3rd party app for a game I like (EVE Online) which requires oauth.
I have decided to do the oauth handling in it's own script and once resolved, put an associative array into the session based on the CharacterID retrieved from oauth.

I am able to successfully output the desired contents of the session array from the /callback/index.php' that handles the oauth requests at the end of the script. However, I want to keep this script "in the background" and somewhat secret, and redirect most of the activity to a '../main.php' in the directory just below.

However, when I finally get to main.php, printing the session returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong? I have searched all day for solutions and have implemented every one of them.

Below are the relevant files:

**session.php**

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET['ID'])) {
        session_id($_GET['ID']);
    }
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    } else {
        $sLocation="http://eve.oriigen.com/eClt";
        header("Location: ".$sLocation);
        exit();
    }

?>
```

**/callback/index.php**

```
<?php require_once '../src/session.php' ?>
<?php require_once 'secret.php' ?>
<?php

    function auth_error($error_message)
    {
        print "There's been an error";
        error_log($error_message);
        exit();
    }

    $sUserAgent = "EVE Contact List Toolkit [eClt]";

    $post_url = "https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token";
    $get_url = "https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/verify";

    $client_id="Basic ".base64_encode($sClientId.":".$sSecretKey);
    $content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $host_url = "login.eveonline.com";

    $aHeaders = array("Authorization: ".$client_id,
                    "Content-type: ".$content_type,
                    "Host: ".$host_url);

    $aPostFields = array("grant_type"=>"authorization_code",
                         "code"=>$_GET["code"]);


    $oCurlRequest = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $sUserAgent);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeaders);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_POST, count($aPostFields));
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($aPostFields));
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $oResult = curl_exec($oCurlRequest);

    if ($oResult===false) {
        auth_error(curl_error($oCurlRequest));
    }

    curl_close($oCurlRequest);

    $aResponse=json_decode($oResult);
    unset($oCurlRequest);
    unset($oResult);


    $sTokenType=$aResponse->token_type;
    $sAuthToken=$aResponse->access_token;
    $iAuthTokenExpire=$aResponse->expires_in;
    $sRefreshToken=$aResponse->refresh_token;

    $sGetHeader="Authorization: ".$sTokenType." ".$sAuthToken;
    $oCurlRequest = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $sUserAgent);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($sGetHeader));
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($oCurlRequest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $oResult = curl_exec($oCurlRequest);

    if ($oResult===false) {
        auth_error(curl_error($oCurlRequest));
    }
    curl_close($oCurlRequest);
    $aResponse=json_decode($oResult);
    unset($oCurlRequest);
    unset($oResult);

    $sCharId=(string)$aResponse->CharacterID;
    $sCharacterName=$aResponse->CharacterName;
    $sExpiresOn=$aResponse->ExpiresOn;
    $sTokenType=$aResponse->TokenType;
    $sCharacterOwnerHash=$aResponse->CharacterOwnerHash;
    $sIntellectualProperty=$aResponse->IntellectualProperty;

/*    $aCharInfo=array("CharID"=>(int)$sCharId,
                    "CharName"=>$sCharacterName,
                    "CharOwnerHash"=>$sCharacterOwnerHash,
                    "ExpiresOn"=>$sExpiresOn,
                    "AuthToken"=>$sAuthToken,
                    "AuthTokenExpIn"=>$iAuthTokenExpire,
                    "RefreshToken"=>$sRefreshToken);*/

    if (!isset($_SESSION[(string)$sCharId])) {
        $_SESSION[(string)$sCharId]=array("CharID"=>(int)$sCharId,
                    "CharName"=>$sCharacterName,
                    "CharOwnerHash"=>$sCharacterOwnerHash,
                    "ExpiresOn"=>$sExpiresOn,
                    "AuthToken"=>$sAuthToken,
                    "AuthTokenExpIn"=>$iAuthTokenExpire,
                    "RefreshToken"=>$sRefreshToken);
    } else {
        $_SESSION["moo"]=0;
    }

    session_write_close();
    $sRedirect="../main.php?ID=".session_id();
    header("Location: ".$sRedirect);
    exit();

/*    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<hr />";
    echo gettype($iCharId);
    echo "<hr />";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($aCharInfo);
    echo "</pre>";*/
?>
```

**../main.php**

```
<?php require_once './src/session.php' ?>
<?php
    //echo "SessionId: ".session_id()."<br />";
    //echo "<hr/>";
    //echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    //echo "</pre>";
?>
[ <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> ]
```

As you can see from the commented sections, I have tried every diagnostic printout I can think of. So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason for passing a session id via `$_GET`?

Comment: I tried with & without. Passing via $_GET was just one more shot at answering the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - per a related question I found only after posting this question:

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797251/notice-unknown-skipping-numeric-key-1-in-unknown-on-line-0/18797380#18797380):

> The PHP session storage mechanism was originally built around "registering" variables, so the keys in $_SESSION must be names that could be treated as variables in their own right. This means that $_SESSION[10] is invalid, because $10 wouldn't be a valid variable name, and since $foo[10] and $foo['10'] refer to the same thing, $_SESSION['10'] is invalid as well.

CharacterID was either and int of a string version of an int, apparently PHP sessions don't like numbers in their array keys...

Comment: `$10` is indeed not allowed